# Dropdown menu is not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazer

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="collapse" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Manage </a> <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="ListUsers"> Users</a> <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="ListRoles"> Roles</a> </div> </li>
```

I tried on Opera, Chrome, Brave, Explorer...

Comment: You've tagged this question with Blazor. Please can you post the C# logic you have for this control, into your question? For people to be able to answer your question, they need a minimum reproducible example of the problem.

Comment: I am sorry for that, not blazer my mistake, logic is very simple 
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult ListUsers()
        {
            var users = userManager.Users;
            return View(users);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, please be sure you use Bootstrap version 4.x.

Then change `data-toggle="collapse"` to `data-toggle="dropdown"` like below:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown"> 
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Manage </a> 
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> 
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="ListUsers"> Users</a> 
        <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration" asp-action="ListRoles"> Roles</a> 
    </div> 
</li>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thаnk you, that works ::)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the MVC strongly type helper methods?
Do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StudentGender, 
            new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))), 
            "Select Gender")
```